# Django: CreateView with pre-populated and uneditable fields specified by query string

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, django-forms

Let's say we have an app called Closet and it has some models:

```
# closet.models.py
class  Outfit(models.Model):
    shirt   = models.ForeignKey(Shirt)
    pants   = models.ForeignKey(Trouser)

class Shirt(models.Model):
    desc    = models.TextField()

class Trouser(models.Model):
    desc    = models.TextField()

class Footwear(models.Model):
    desc    = models.TextField
```

Using generic detail view, it's easy to make the URL conf for details on each of those:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^closet/outfit/(?P<pk>\d+)$',     DetailView(model=Outfit),       name='outfit_detail'),
    url(r'^closet/shirt/(?P<pk>\d+)$',          DetailView(model=Shirt),        name='shirt_detail'),
    url(r'^closet/trouser/(?P<pk>\d+)$',        DetailView(model=Trouser),      name='trouser_detail'),
    url(r'^closet/footwear/(?P<pk>\d+)$',       DetailView(model=Footwear),     name='footwear_detail'),
)
```

What I'd like to do next is define the views that will create a new object of each type.  I would like to do this with an extended version of `CreateView` which will be able to handle data on pre-populated fields.

Specifically, I want the following behavior:

1. If I visit `/closet/outfit/new` I want to get a standard `ModelForm` for the `Outfit` model with everything blank and everything editable.
2. If I visit `/closet/outfit/new/?shirt=1` I want to see all the fields I saw in case 1) but I want the shirt field to be pre-populated with the shirt with pk=1.  Additionally, I want the shirt field to be displayed as un-editable. If the form is submitted and is deemed to be invalid, when the form is redisplayed I want the shirt field to continue to be un-editable.
3. If I visit `/closet/outfit/new/?shirt=1&trouser=2` I want to see all the fields I saw in case 1) but now both the shirt and trouser fields should be preopoulated and uneditable.  (I.e. only the `footwear` field should be editable.)

In general, is this possible?  I.e. can the querystring modify the structure of the displayed form in this way?  I want to accomplish this in the DRYest way possible.  My gut tells me this should be doable with class based views and perhaps would involve `model_form_factory` but I can't get the logic straight in my mind.  In particular, I wasn't sure whether it was possible to have the class-based-view access the `request.REQUEST` (i.e. the `request.POST` or `request.GET` parameters) at the time that the `ModelForm` is being constructed.

Perhaps its possible only if I use different querystring keywords for the locked fields.  I.e. perhaps the URL's need to be: `/closet/outfit/new/?lock_shirt=1` and `/closet/outfit/new?lock_shirt=1&lock_trouser=2`.  Perhaps if its done that way the `POST` handler would be handed both a list of locked fields (for the purposes of form display in the browser) along with a regular list of all the model fields for the purpose of actually creating the object.

Why do I want this:  In the template for the `footwear_detail` I would want to be able to make a tag like

```
<a href="{% url outfit_new %}?footwear={{object.pk}}>Click to create a new outfit with this footwear!</a>
```

In general, it would be really useful to be able to make links to forms whose "structure" (not just values) changes depending on the querystring passed.

---

Responding to the great suggestion from Berislav Lopac:

So I went ahead and did:

```
class CreateViewWithPredefined(CreateView):
    def get_initial(self):
    return self.request.GET
```

This gets me 90% of what I need.  But let me flesh out the situation a bit more.  Say I add two fields to the Outfit model: `headgear = models.ManyToManyField('headgear')` and `awesomeness_rating = models.FloatField()`.

Two problems:

1. If I visit `/closet/outfit/new/?awesomeness_rating=10` then my form pre-fills with `[u'10']` instead of just filling with `10`.  Is there a filter I should use in my template or a bit of processing I can add to my view to make the formatting more appropriate?
2. If I want to pre-specify a few pieces of headwear, what is the right format to pass what feels like a python list in through a query string?  I.e. should I do `/closet/outfit/new/?headgear=1,2,3`?  If so, will Django correctly figure out that I'd like to pre-select the 3 pieces of headgear with those ID's?

---

Continuing to work on this...

```
class CreateViewWithPredefined(CreateView):
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CreateView, self).get_initial()
        for k, v in self.request.GET.iterlists():
            if len(v) > 1:
                initial.update({ k : v })
            else:
                initial.update({ k : v[0] })
        return initial
```

This seems to kill 2 birds with one stone: numerical data gets coerced from unicode to numerical and it flattens lists when possible (as intended).  Need to check if this works on multi-valued fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `self.request`, anywhere in a CBV. :-)

OK, let me make this answer more comprehensive. Basically, what you want is the `get_initial` method, which is contributed by the [FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin). Override it to populate the initial values for your fields.

Comment: This is a great first step.  I have two questions about how to implement this.  Please see edits to the original post above. I think for my purposes, I will wind up going this route since it gets the gist.  But to the extent that others might care about the original problem: does anyone have a solution to the original question...instead of just pre-filling the form with initial data, is there a way to have the pre-filled fields actually display as locked?

Comment: One way is to add the `readonly` attribute to the input element, maybe in the `get_form` method of the view. You could take the `request.GET` fields (or even better use your `get_initial` in order to avoid duplication of code) and modify the widget of each field that has a value there.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm quite new to this and am still having issues with the unicode formatting.  I understand that all entries in a QueryDict that I get from `request.GET` will be formatted as Unicode strings.  Is there a general way to convert a unicode to its native python datatype?  So if I do `/closet/outfit/new/?awesomeness_level=10` I want to make sure that the field prepopulates with 10 instead of [u'10]...

Comment: Why would you want that? HTML fields always contain text values and are unaware of their values' types.

Comment: Everything is easy if each variable has only 1 value.  But if you have a querystring of `?var=a,b` that's ambiguous since maybe you want `a,b` to be the only text value of var, but maybe you want `a` and `b` to be two separate values.  You can avoid the ambiguity by doing `?var=a&var=b`.  Multiple selects will give strings like the latter.  So I guess I was hoping there would be a nice pair of functions: one to take dictionaries of variables and turn them into querystrings (unambiguously) and the other to take get/post parameters and turn them into dictionaries.